# Spring JPA comparing json with string

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have the entity in my `spring boot` & `hibernate` app like this

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "employers")
class Employer(
    @Id val id: Long

    @Type(JsonType::class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    val jsondata: String
)
```

and I am trying to run the query like this from `spring data jpa`

```kotlin
@Query(
    value = "select * from employers where e.jsondata::text = :jsondata"
    nativeQuery = true
)
fun findByJsonData(@Param("jsondata") jsondata: String)
```

but when I run the query, I get this error:

> Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.JdbcMapping.getJdbcValueBinder()" because "jdbcMapping" is null

but when I run the same query in postgres console

```sql
select * from employers e where e.jsondata::text = '{"id":1}'
```

it works perfectly.

I am using Postgres v14.4 and Spring Boot v3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should have next one body:

```
  @Query("select emp from Employer emp where cast(emp.jsonData as STRING) = :jsondata")
  fun findByJsonData(@Param("jsondata") jsondata: String)
```

It is going to help you to fetch the result that you are wanting.